# ng2-img-cropper reduce image quality

Tags: image, angular

I'm having an issue with ng2-img-cropper.

When I try to upload a large size [image](http://www.slovakrail.sk/fileadmin/Obrazky2/portrety/kovac_zssk_02.jpg) (4000x6000) , its quality is reduced.
Here is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/V91mKCNkBQZB5QO2MUP4/) for reproducing the issue. 
I tried playing with the cropperSetting but it didn't solve my issue.

Has anyone encountered similar issue ?

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573339/using-cropper-js-image-quality-get-reduced-after-cropping