# User Image Upload in React without quality Loss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, frontend

I'm working at a company where a File Uploader was already implemented, but for some reason we are saving the photo and its quality is greatly reduced. Basically, I want to know what the easiest way is to implement a component where a user can upload a profile photo or logo, and we can save it without losing quality. I also want to be able to resize it to various dimensions without losing quality. I don't necessarily need a cropper either, I want the user to be able to upload the photo and we display the full image, just resized without quality loss. Techstack is using JS and React.

```
class FileUpload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fileRef = createRef();
    this.imgCanvas = createRef();
    this.previousMoveX = 0;
    this.previousMoveY = 0;

    this.state = {
      showUploadModal: false || props.showUploadModal,
      img: '',
      imgControl: false,
      imgControlZoom: 0,
      imgControlMove: false,
      imgControlX: 0,
      imgControlY: 0,
    };

    this.onImgRead = this.onImgRead.bind(this);
    this.onChangeImage = this.onChangeImage.bind(this);
    this.onChangeZoom = this.onChangeZoom.bind(this);
    this.onStartMove = this.onStartMove.bind(this);
    this.onMouseMove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { img, imgControlZoom, imgControlX, imgControlY } = this.state;
    if (img === '') return;
    let canvas = this.imgCanvas.current;
    if (canvas === null) return;

    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let imgNode = new Image();
    imgNode.onload = () => {
      const s = parseInt(
        Math.min(imgNode.width, imgNode.height) / ((imgControlZoom + 100) / 100)
      );
      const k = canvas.width / s;
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(
        imgNode,
        0,
        0,
        imgNode.width,
        imgNode.height,
        imgControlX + (s - imgNode.width) * 0.5 * k,
        imgControlY + (s - imgNode.height) * 0.5 * k,
        imgNode.width * k,
        imgNode.height * k
      );
    };
    imgNode.src = img;
  }

  onChangeImage(e) {
    const input = e.target;
    const { files } = e.target;
    if (files === 0) return;

    const file = files[0];
    if (file.size > FILE_SIZE) {
      toast.error(FILE_SIZE_VALIDATION);
      return;
    }
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = ev => {
      input.value = '';
      this.onImgRead(ev.target.result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file, 'UTF-8');
  }
```

Comment: Does this server have compression? Does the user know that there image is low quality? Whats the max filesize a user can upload? Are you attempting to load a low res copy of the full res in the db? Is the image multered? Whats the lowest resolution you can get away with before its bad UX?

Comment: Why do you think that quality loss is caused by react? React can't do that on its own, your problem in in server side.

Comment: @isAif not unless hes lazy loading by rendering a low res copy of the full res in the db. But good point.

Comment: I didn't particularly think it was React, just the way the component was initially written. This isn't my code, I'm in charge of fixing it.

Comment: To answer you user67, I think all the image rendering is done client side, and the image is being saved with a GraphQL query. Max file size is 5mb. On the server we're just uploading photo to AWS S3 bucket with base64upload method

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React, and is not usually implemented on the client with JS, unless you are using NodeJS on the server. This feature is usually implemented on the server. Such as [http_image_filter_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) module of nginx.

For lossy image formats （such as jpeg）, any change will again lose the quality of the image, although this loss is usually very small. If you really need to have a very high quality of the image, you need to convert them to lossless image formats (such as png) on the server first.

Comment: I think the image rendering is done client side. Would it be worth to just have the client upload the image directly, and do image processing server side for performance?

Comment: But the images are stored on the server， unless your images are disposable

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573339/using-cropper-js-image-quality-get-reduced-after-cropping) answer is helpful